# gsutil copy failing with exception can't start new thread

Tags: python, copy, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-platform

I am trying copy from local to google cloud storage

```
String gsutilCommand = String.format("gsutil -m cp -r %s %s", localPath, gcsPath);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "bash", "-c", gsutilCommand });
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();

  Process Process-6:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in 
  _bootstrap
  error: can't start new thread
  self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1716, in _ApplyThreads
       status_queue=status_queue)
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2006, in __init__
       worker_thread.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 745, in start
       _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
  error: can't start new thread
       self.run()
```

Comment: Are you on OS X? It might be a ulimit issue.

Comment: no, ubuntu @jterrace

Comment: Can you check the value of `ulimit -u` ?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (python3.8, CentOS 8):

Go into your .boto settings, uncomment and change the "parallel" values to 1 as follows:

```
[GSUtil]                                                                                                                               
parallel_process_count = 1                                                                                                             
parallel_thread_count = 1
```

This resolved gsutil complaining about threading even in the absence of using the -m flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newer *gcloud* command instead of *gsutil*
you can run these commands from a shell. I tested this on Linux.

```
$ gcloud config set storage/process_count 1
$ gcloud config set storage/thread_count 1
```

The .boto file has been removed from the newer installations.